# How can know the subnet mask in IPv6 network?

Tags: ipv6

How the host can know the subnet mask in the IPv6 network, in case the network does not use the default subnet mask which is /64. for example the subnet mask of the network is /88, How can the IPv6 host know the subnet mask is 88 and is not 64?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The router advertisement contains the prefix length of advertised prefixes.

Comment: What about DHCPv6

Comment: DHCPv6 only provides addresses. Prefixes and their lengths still come from RA